# How to start an elevated console (cmd.exe) from an elevated program just as if that was done manually?

Tags: c++, uac, createprocess

I have a Visual C++ x32 app on Windows 7 that is running elevated with the UAC execution level set to requireAdministrator in the manifest. It starts a console with:

```
 system("C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe");
```

But this console does not behave as if it was started with the "run as Administrator" from the context menu.

I noticed a difference, when I checked the power-management which the manually started "cmd.exe" reported as:

```
C:\Windows\system32>powercfg -requests
DISPLAY:
None.

SYSTEM:
None.

AWAYMODE:
None.
```

While the programmatically started "cmd.exe" reports this as:

```
C:\Windows\System32>powercfg -requests
DISPLAY:
None.

SYSTEM:
[DRIVER] ?
[DRIVER] ?
[DRIVER] ?
[DRIVER] ?
[DRIVER] ?
[DRIVER] ?
[DRIVER] ?
[DRIVER] ?

AWAYMODE:
None.
```

I also tried to start it with "ShellExecuteEx" and the lpVerb set to "runas" but with the same result.

How can I start the "cmd.exe" programatically from an elevated process and behave exactly as if I started it with "run as Administrator" manually?

Comment: Specify your version of Windows, please.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph first sentence: Visual C++ x32 app on `Windows 7`

Comment: Have you tried the [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) API?

Comment: If the cmd.exe process was not started with elevation, the `powercfg -requests` command will say `You do not have the permissions required to perform this action.`.

Answer (score 0):

Well I can currently think of two options (maybe some more will come up later):

1. If you can use an intermediate tool:

   Using `psexec` running:

   ```
   system("C:\\utils\\PsExec.exe -i -s -d cmd.exe");
   ```

   Opens a `cmd` that prints:

   ```
   DISPLAY:
   None.

   SYSTEM:
   None.

   AWAYMODE:
   None.
   ```

   When running `powercfg -requests`
2. You could use [`OpenProcessToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379295.aspx) function and steal a token from your favorite process that

   runs as `nt authority\system` (e.g `csrss.exe` or `services.exe`) then you can use [`ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378612.aspx) or [`CreateProcessAsUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429.aspx).